# Is there a daily pattern in closing questions?

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions

Anecdotally, I get the impression that more questions are closed at night then in the morning (my timezone is UTC -5). Are there times of day where questions of the same quality remain open longer? Is there a time of day where low-quality questions (which sometimes do reveal intriguing ways of thinking about chemistry) have a higher chance of getting an answer? Once the question is closed, the only way the OP will get feedback is through comments, if folks even spend the time to look at closed questions.

Comment: Not a terrible topic to bring up, but could you state some of the implications you think this timing might have/what you want for input from us? There isn't much to answer.

Comment: Since closing is (mostly) done by the community, questions get closed whenever people are active. Anecdotally, most people who close are in Europe/US, so it makes sense that it happens at night. I don't see a problem, though. If a question should be closed, then there's nothing wrong with closing it, and if they need feedback on the question itself then the comment section is the correct place for it, as the answer section is for answers. If questions are being closed unfairly, then that's another issue, but it doesn't seem to be what you're concerned about.

Comment: I agree that there is no problem. It is possible that new users might get a different impression of the site depending on when they use it. Sometimes, they will see that most of the recent questions are closed, and sometimes they are not.

Answer (score 7):

I ran this script to return the number of questions closed per hour. I'm in **Greenwich Mean Time** so I assume these results are too.

```sql
SELECT
  DATEPART(hh, ClosedDate),
  COUNT(*) AS ClosedQuestions
FROM PostsWithDeleted
WHERE PostTypeID=1 AND ClosedDate IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY DATEPART(hh, ClosedDate)
ORDER BY DATEPART(hh, ClosedDate)
```

[image: Closed Questions GMT]

It seems to correlate pretty well with the number of questions ask per hour.

```sql
SELECT
  DATEPART(hh, CreationDate),
  COUNT(*) AS QuestionAsked
FROM PostsWithDeleted
WHERE PostTypeID=1
GROUP BY DATEPART(hh, CreationDate)
ORDER BY DATEPART(hh, CreationDate)
```

[image: Questions Asked GMT]

Comment: That's interesting. So it seems that the community is always active (the more question asked the more closed) or we have a shift of one day.. would it be possible to map the query to see which countries ask more questions and which one close more questions?

Comment: I don’t think so. Users input their own location so any queries on location return things like “221B Baker St.” and “Gryffindor House”!

Comment: Hmmm, the absence of a lag between asking/closing and the timing around European dinner/American lunch time suggests either "question fatigue" (overburdened reviewers) or "hunger/post-prandial-induced poor question intolerance". That spatial data for poster/reviewer location would be nice to have (if only the continent).

Comment: I think most of the bad questions come from Slytherin....

Comment: I've created this graph for India, USA and UK: http://oi64.tinypic.com/2ce15xs.jpg. It's based on manually chosen search terms so it's probably not very representative.  I used this very primitive code https://data.stackexchange.com/chemistry/query/1000827#resultSets. I'll update it when I get time.